# Cron Expression - Every 5 seconds between 7am and 8pm...?

Tags: cron, quartz.net

I have the following Cron expression i use with Quartz.net:

> 0/5 * * ? * MON-FRI

Basically, every 5 seconds, Mondays - Fridays.

How can I modify this so it only runs between 7am and 8pm on those days?

Comment: THE RIGHT ANSWER  to this is `0 0/5 7-20 ? * MON-FRI`  _________________________________  
CAUTION : The answer checked as correct below is WRONG :-)

Comment: The Above Answer is for every 5 Minutes. For every 5 Seconds that would be : `0/5 * 7-20 ? * MON-FRI`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This entry would be for *every five minutes* between 7:00 and 7:55 on Mon to Fri:

```
0/5 7  * * 1-5    who /usr/bin/what
```

as user `who` running `/usr/bin/what`.  To my knowledge, the smallest unit that `cron` can be configured with is a minute.

But you could start something at 7:00am on Mon to Fri which then itself would

```
do { 
   work 
   sleep(5)      // or sleep(4) or whichever, depending on length of work task
} while (not yet 08:00am)
```

which is not that hard to put together.

Comment: sorry, i should of clarified-
I'm using Quartz.net - it has CronExpression support:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Comment: Thanks for your help - In the end I came up with:
0 0/5 7-20 ? * MON-FRI

Which is every 5 minutes (a little diff. from my initial request) but this works.

Comment: Oh, right, I missed the 8pm.  If you want to run the last one at 20:55 then 7-20 for the hour field is indeed correct.