# Quartz.NET cront Trigger set at 23

Tags: c#, .net-core, quartz.net

I try to use Quart.NET scheduler for some job that are to reproduce every 5 second.
I use a CRON trigger set like: `0/5 0 0 ? * * *`
The first time, when i start, the trigger was called. 
**Then the NEXT_FIRE_TIME will be set to the 23 of the day and not 5 second after.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cron Expression - Every 5 seconds between 7am and 8pm...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178652/cron-expression-every-5-seconds-between-7am-and-8pm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was the cron expression...

---

The correct cron is:

```
0/5 * * ? * * *
```

---

If you have problem you can check here: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Answer (score -1):

You should use `1/5 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *` It will work.
More information on [Cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/?2)
And [Wiki Pedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: I Provided the correct cron. You can test it. Why dislike the answer?